# 他サイトから移行されたことを示す説明文が分かりにくい

Tags: バグ, 完了, 移行

先日、[Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) からスタック・オーバーフローへ質問が[移行](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/341401)されてきました。

- 移行元 (リダイレクトします): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72086
- 移行先: [javaで、ここから更に＂00:00にfalseと表示する＂を追加したいのですがどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59271/19110)

この際、移行時のメッセージとして以下のように表示されました。

[image]

> この質問は、students, teachers, and linguists wanting to discuss the finer points of the Japanese language のサイトから移行されました。

しかしこの説明は、Japanese Language Stack Exchange を元から知っていないと分かりにくいですし、元サイトへのリンクがありませんし、何より大事な部分が日本語ではありません。また、私の知っている典型的な移行時のメッセージはこのようなものではなく、元サイトの URL が示されるものです。

[image]

> **migrated** from cs.stackexchange.com Sep 15 at 21:26
>   This question came from our site for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science.

Traducir で string を検索してみると、後者のメッセージは [string として登録されていて和訳も済んでいる](https://ja.traducir.win/string/4061)ものの、前者は登録されていないようです。

おそらく過去に移行時のメッセージが変更された際、更新が日本語版スタック・オーバーフローまで反映されなかったバグなのではないでしょうか。後者の方がメッセージとして分かりやすいので、後者にしていただきたいです。ご確認お願いいたします。

---

To Community Team:

A message for migrated questions seems to be not updated. Currently it's like "This question is migrated from $Audience$" but it should be [this string](https://ja.traducir.win/string/4061) according to other SE sites. Also, the current message is not registered to Traducir as a string. Could you update this message?

Comment: 長い `$Audience$` (サイトの説明)より、シンプルな `$ShortName$` (サイト名)で表示された方が見やすい/分かりやすいんじゃないかなぁとも思ったり。翻訳で設定すれば反映されるのかな？

Comment: 翻訳で中身を変えるのは良くない気がするので、その場合はそう変更して欲しい旨をメタに投稿することになりそうです。

Comment: クローズや移行に関する説明欄に若干の変更があったようですが、現在でもこの問題は残っていますか？

Comment: 現状[メッセージが表示されないバグ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3143/19110)があるので確認できない状況な気がしています。

Comment: 他サイトから移行されてきた質問は正しく表示されているものがほとんどです。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31973

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[通知の見直し](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700) などを経て、この問題は解決しているかもしれません。

他サイトから移行されてきた質問
[VirtualBoxとvagrantを使って仮想マシンを立ち上げたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/54591)

**現在の表示**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

表示に使用される文字列
https://ja.traducir.win/string/12893