# 移行されてきた一部の質問で、移行元の情報が表示されていない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 移行

### 不具合事象

過去に「[javaで、ここから更に＂00:00にfalseと表示する＂を追加したいのですがどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59271/java%E3%81%A7-%E3%81%93%E3%81%93%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%AB-0000%E3%81%ABfalse%E3%81%A8%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)」という質問が、 [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com) からスタック・オーバーフローへ移行されました。そのため、この質問には [Japanese Language Stack Exchange](https://japanese.stackexchange.com) から移行されたことが表示されるはずですが、実際には何も表示されていません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一方で、 [cubick さんがコメントしてくださったように](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3143/%E9%81%8E%E5%8E%BB%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%9F%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E7%A7%BB%E8%A1%8C%E5%85%83%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment2970_3143)、その他の[移行されてきた質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31973)では移行元の情報が表示されています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もしこの動作が正常なものであれば、移行元を示す文章だけではなく、移行された投稿であることを通知するボックス自体を削除してしまったほうが、後から投稿を読むときに戸惑わずに済むと思います。

---

### 関連投稿

- [Blank notification shown on the top of questions migrated more than 60 days ago on localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340151)

---

### 追記 (2020-01-16)

[@cubick さんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3189/32986)に書かれているとおり、この不具合は解消されたように見えましたが、先日スタック・オーバーフローからメタ スタック・オーバーフローへ移行されてきた質問で**同様の問題が再現した**ため、質問を未解決状態に戻しておきます。

- [スタックオーバーフローのアカウントに複数の認証サービスを紐付けるには？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3200/32986) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200116130951/https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3200/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AB%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AB%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E7%B4%90%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF))

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 同じ様に移行された [他の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31973) では表示されているので、この質問固有の問題な気がしますが、MSEの方にも投稿してみました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340151

Comment: @supa 問題の再発について、cubickさんがMSEへ投稿してくれていたのを見つけました https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342089/341401 ／ 一旦完了した問題が再発した場合、新しいメタ投稿として投稿いただくのも良いかもしれません（ [完了] タグの付け直しが発生しないため）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメント欄でも伝えた通り、[MSEでバグ報告を行ったところ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340151) 修正されました。

**現在の表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

"新しい通知" は少し前にも仕様変更があったようで、[他サイトから移行されてから60日後にボックス通知が非表示になります](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340733) (一定の信用度があれば、各投稿のタイムラインから移行された履歴は確認可能)。

ただしこの変更後も今回問題の出ている投稿では "空の通知" が残ったままだったので、この点も再度MSEで報告したところ問題が修正されたようです。

Comment: この問題は修正されました。 詳細については、次の投稿をご覧ください：[リンク](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341791/51)