# スタックオーバーフローのアカウントに複数の認証サービスを紐付けるには？

Tags: サポート, アカウント

例えばGoogleアカウントとGitHubアカウント両方を、自身の唯一のスタックオーバーフローアカウントに紐付けたい場合、どのようにすればいいでしょうか？

もしくは、ドキュメントのリンクが存在しましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4):

ご希望の操作についてはプロフィールページの設定から変更することができます。

現在のアカウントに対して別の認証サービスを追加するには、以下リンク先のヘルプを参照してください。

参考:
[アカウントにログイン資格情報を追加または削除する方法は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)