# 他サイトに移行済み質問の説明文を見直したい

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

「他のサイトに移行された質問」を開いた際、移行先のラベルとして該当サイトの"説明文"が表示されますが、やや分かりづらいように感じます。

> 例:
>   スタック・オーバフロー メタ
>   → "プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心な人" で回答できるため...
>
> Stack Overflow
>   → "professional and enthusiast programmers" で回答できるため...

一方で、他サイトからスタック・オーバーフローに移行された場合には、単純に"サイト名"で表示されます。

> 例:
>   この質問は "スタック・オーバーフロー" で回答できるため...

できれば"サイト名"での表示に統一した方がすっきりして分かりやすいのかなと思っています。

---

なお、該当箇所の翻訳は以下のStringで管理されており、サイト名や説明文の箇所は特別な変数を参照しています。

他サイトから移行
https://ja.traducir.win/string/12893

他サイトに移行
https://ja.traducir.win/string/12568

Comment: 関連: [他サイトから移行されたことを示す説明文が分かりにくい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3104/19110)

Comment: MSE にも投稿したところ "レビュー中" になりました。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340367